# Using cursor created by helping class to fill ListView

Tags: android, cursor, sqlite

I do have a question regarding to this code fragment.

I am having a SQLiteDatabase which is connected through a "Manager" class. I am calling the following function:

```
        try {
        String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(_id) };
        SQLiteDatabase dbReadable = Db.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor =  dbReadable.rawQuery(sqlQuery, selectionArgs);
        return cursor;

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.e(tag, "SQLiteException: /n " + sqlQuery);
    }
    return null;
```

The sqlQuery is a valid SQL query as it does not throw an SQLiteException().
So what I want to du is providing a cursor with several rows of my Database to an other class, so that those Information will be shown in a ListView.

```
Cursor cursor = Manager.getChildren(id);

mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context ,R.layout.small_listitem, cursor , uiBindFrom, uiBindTo,0);

setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

However anything I a am doing breaks my app or the ListView doesn't show anything.

So basically I have two questions: is that the right way? -I don't want to create a List of the result.
Secondly: Where do I need to close() my database. Or is it enough when closing the cursor.

I've tryed it the whole day and I think I'm stuck a little.

I've seen someone asked for Logcat. This is what I get:

```
07-12 00:50:07.868: E/AndroidRuntime(14799): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-12 00:50:07.868: E/AndroidRuntime(14799): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.dornathal.planyourmeals/de.dornathal.planyourmeals.view.FoodInformation}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-12 00:50:07.868: E/AndroidRuntime(14799):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
07-12 00:50:07.868: E/AndroidRuntime(14799):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-12 00:50:07.868: E/AndroidRuntime(14799):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-12 00:50:07.868: E/AndroidRuntime(14799):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
07-12 00:50:07.868: E/AndroidRuntime(14799):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-12 00:50:07.868: E/AndroidRuntime(14799):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-12 00:50:07.868: E/AndroidRuntime(14799):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-12 00:50:07.868: E/AndroidRuntime(14799):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-12 00:50:07.868: E/AndroidRuntime(14799):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-12 00:50:07.868: E/AndroidRuntime(14799):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-12 00:50:07.868: E/AndroidRuntime(14799):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-12 00:50:07.868: E/AndroidRuntime(14799):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-12 00:50:07.868: E/AndroidRuntime(14799): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-12 00:50:07.868: E/AndroidRuntime(14799):    at de.dornathal.planyourmeals.view.FoodBoxPicture.onCreateView(FoodBoxPicture.java:37)
07-12 00:50:07.868: E/AndroidRuntime(14799):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
07-12 00:50:07.868: E/AndroidRuntime(14799):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
07-12 00:50:07.868: E/AndroidRuntime(14799):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
07-12 00:50:07.868: E/AndroidRuntime(14799):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-12 00:50:07.868: E/AndroidRuntime(14799):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
07-12 00:50:07.868: E/AndroidRuntime(14799):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:551)
07-12 00:50:07.868: E/AndroidRuntime(14799):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1133)
07-12 00:50:07.868: E/AndroidRuntime(14799):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4475)
07-12 00:50:07.868: E/AndroidRuntime(14799):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1929)
07-12 00:50:07.868: E/AndroidRuntime(14799):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: [Quote]Android, you don't normally need to close the database at all[/Quote] I have expierenced many exceptions telling me the database was npt closed. They appeared after opening readable and writable databases. However the exceptions were only thrown after reopening these databases. --Now I have added all close() functions at requested positions and now I'm no longer getting Exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create another class. Some thing like a model class the one that can be easily used by the UI (Listview) and the Manager(SQLIte helper class). So after you query from database, use the returned cursor to fill a list of Model class, which you can send to the Listview class and it doesnt need to handle any database class. This would be preferred approach as UI should have an abstraction to the database stuff.

e.g. Model class

{

String firstName;
String lastName
}

Filled using database
and the list view probably uses an arraylist, filed with objects of model class

// From your error it seems you just have a nullpointer exception u either post FoodBoxPicture.java class or check wat is null at line 37 in that class
But do try to use a new class like i mentioned above,
would make things easier

Comment: Thank you. I have now created my own class of ArrayAdapter which I fill with an <ClassName>[] and this ArrayAdapter will be provided by the function.